# Five Consecutive Integers divisible by a square greater than 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have the task of finding 5 consecutive 
integers of the 
form {x, x+1, x+2, x+3, x+4, x+5}
where each number in the sequence 
is divisible by a square  k greater than 1..

I tried to write a simple JAVA program
to find a sequence of that form by checking
if each number in the sequence = 0 mod k

But that can't be possible, how would I go about
finding these numbers?

Comment: There can't be one $k$ which divides $x$ and $x+1$, other than $k=1$. So it has to be a different square for each element.

Comment: Do you know the Chinese remainder theorem? Are you allowed to find any solution, or does it have to be the smallest?

Comment: I can find any solution

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Except that two of $x, \ldots, x+5$ may be divisible by $4$.

Comment: You say 5 consecutive integers, but $x,x+1,\ldots,x+5$, is 6 consecutive integers.

Comment: @B.Goddard Good catch.

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A045882](https://oeis.org/A045882) and links there.

Comment: Are looking for the answer or an algorithm to find the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chinese remainder theorem:

$$\begin{align}x&\equiv 0\pmod{4}\\
x&\equiv -1\pmod{9}\\
x&\equiv -2\pmod{25}\\
x&\equiv -3\pmod{49}\\
x&\equiv -5\pmod{121}
\end{align}$$

That's gonna be ugly.

If you only need five, then you can ignore the last line and you get $$x\equiv 29348\pmod{4\cdot 9\cdot 24\cdot 49}.$$ Then $x,x+4$ are divisible by $4$, $x+1$ is divisible by $9$, $x+2$ is divisible by $25$, and $x+3$ is divisible by $49$.

Comment: Very mechanical, though, and since this implies an answer less than $4\cdot9\cdot25\cdot49\cdot121 = 5336100$, all of the calculations can be done straightforwardly using standard 32-bit integer arithmetic.

Comment: And it's even easier if the OP really mean $5$ consecutive, rather than six.

Comment: Thomas what about a numver thats congruent to -4? you have 0, -1, -2, -3,  -5 but you skip -4

Comment: If $x\equiv 0\pmod{4}$ then $x\equiv -4\pmod{4}$. @user203042

Comment: They don't have to be "in order."

Comment: Where did I say they had to be in order? I was finding a solution. The smallest is probably smaller, but if the goal is finding a solution, and you don't have a computer, this will be the easier approach than anything else. @DougM

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Fair enough.

Comment: Indeed, I found my answer (for five consecutives) without a computer program (but with a non-programmable calculator.) I got $x\equiv 8\pmod{36}$ and $x\equiv -52\pmod{49\cdot 25}$.. Then I saw $49\cdot 25=36\cdot 24+1$, which makes combining them somewhat easy. @DougM

Answer (score 0):

The formulation you give ($x,x+1,\ldots,x+5$) actually has $6$ consecutive values. The values for such $x$ below $100000$:

$$22020, 24647, 30923, 47672, 55447, 57120, 73447, 74848, 96675$$

Finding $5$ consecutive values is easier; the smallest such sequence is $844,845,846,847,848$, which are multiples of $4,169,9,121,16$ respectively.

Comment: Interesting. $844 \neq 29348(mod4⋅9⋅24⋅49)$ [sic] as stated in @ThomasAndrews post.

Comment: This is the result of a straight search, so as you can see one of the squares involved is $13^2=169$ and the other factor squares are in a different order.